# Image processing in CUDA

Tags: image-processing, cuda

Can anyone please suggest free,easy to use and access library for image processing in CUDA?

Comment: What kind of image processing tasks are you working on?

Comment: I want to show that image X looks something and when i apply filtering it looks like some other thing is is possible with it?

Answer (score 2):

OpenCV is a free image processing library that has CUDA enabled functionality built in.

The wiki on ported functions:

http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/OpenCV_GPU#List_of_Ported_Functions

Comment: I want to show that image X looks something and when i apply filtering it looks like some other thing is is possible with it?

Comment: Displaying it will be up to you, but if you're wanting to the actual filtering, OpenCV should be able to do something for you.

Comment: An alternative for lower-level programming is to use Nvidias NPP library, which is also free.

Comment: Is NPP available for toolkit 4.0?

Comment: +1 nice to know they baked CUDA in. How can you tell what's been enhanced?

Comment: NPP is available for all versions of CUDA I think. Added link to ported functions.